# How to create an array of images?

Tags: image, blackberry

I need to create a simple array of some images. So that later on I can traverse through the array easily using a loop and access all the images one by one.

Just tell me the declaration part of storing the images into an array.

I will be having 5 images named as 1.png to 5.png which I need to access.
Will it be a string array or integer array ?

Comment: It's on the blackberry by looking at the tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array of [ImageIcon](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html):

```
ImageIcon[] images = new ImageIcon[5];
images[0] = new ImageIcon("path/to/image");
....
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is confusing. You clearly know what an array is and how to use it, but you don't know what type to use? Why, whichever type you *want* to use, of course. You could use String, or whatever class you usually use to represent an image.